# Ubuntu will not install with dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have a Desktop with a 1 TB HD and Win 7 installed.  When I try to install Ubuntu as a dual boot system the only option it allows is to write over Win 7.  I've installed dual boot versions on other computers with no problems.

Comment: so do you know how to install dualboot ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you already have 4 primary partitions, which is the maximum. If you already have 4 primary partitions, Ubuntu cannot add another partition for itself.

You would have to rethink your partition table. For example, you could delete one partition and create an extended partition instead. Extended partitions are like wrappers which can contains many partitions.

Comment: Had two partitions, didn't work.  Deleted 1 partitions and made entire drive 1 win 7 partition.  didn't work.